# NSUserDefaults, like regedit?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsuserdefaults

Ok, since i'm new to obj-c and have a background in windows developing, i'm searching for the counterpart of Regedit.

I've understand that i should use NSUserDefaults, right?

So, i have created two functions, one for setting and one for getting values. They look like this: (And yea... ignore my silly functions names) :)

```
//SET:
-(void)SetRegeditValue:(NSString*)Name:(NSString*)Value
{
    NSUserDefaults *ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:Value,Name, nil];
    [ud registerDefaults:dict];
}
//GET:
-(NSString*)GetRegeditValue:(NSString *)Name
{
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *get = [prefs stringForKey:Name];

    if(get)
        return get;
    else
        return @"Not found!";
}
```

And i use them like this:

```
//TO SET:
SetRegitValue:@"my_value":@"my_value_name";
//TO GET:
GetRegeditName:@"my_value_name";
```

I don't know if this is the "right" way to do it, but it works.
The only thing is that when i kill the app, it does not remember these values and i get "Not found!". Is there something i have to set so it REALLY saves these variables?

Oh, i'm building a cocoa application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `registerDefaults:` method is used to assign default values which get returned when you ask for an undefined key. To actually store a value, you need to use one of the `set*:forKey:` methods. Specifically, you should use `setObject:forKey:` since you are saving strings, which are objects.

```
- (void)SetRegeditValue:(NSString *)name :(NSString *)value {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:value forKey:name];
}
```

I used the same argument order that your code did, but note that it does not match the example you showed, which passed the value first.

Answer (score 0):

The docs for the `synchronize` method of NSUserDefaults say, *"Writes any modifications to the persistent domains to disk"*.
...and...
*"Because this method is automatically invoked at periodic intervals, use this method only if you cannot wait for the automatic synchronization (for example, if your application is about to exit)"*.

Since you say you're killing the app when you see the problem, perhaps you're in the category of needing explicit synchronization.